# Add aws icons to powerpoint library

Tags: powerpoint

I'm trying to prepare AWS architecture dig but need AWS icons.

I went to the below link and downloaded the icons.

https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/icons/

Now, How can I add these downloaded icons into the powerpoint presentation?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: The PowerPoint icons are served up by Microsoft's computers. As users, we can't add any new material to the collection. There may be third-party add-ins that let you add your own icons to a separate feature. Or use a different set of icons, such as those from The Noun Project (they also provide a free add-in to access them easily) https://thenounproject.com/

Answer (score 0):

Download AWS Architecture Icons:

Visit the official AWS Architecture Icons page. AWS provides a collection of icons for use in architecture diagrams.
Download the icon set that you require. They are typically available in various formats, including PNG and SVG.
Unzip the Downloaded File:

Once downloaded, extract the files from the zipped folder.
Open PowerPoint:

Launch PowerPoint on your computer.
Insert Icons into Your PowerPoint Slide:

Go to the slide where you want to add the AWS icons.
Click on the "Insert" tab in the PowerPoint ribbon.
Choose "Pictures" if your icons are in PNG format, or "Insert SVG" if they're in SVG format.
Browse to the location where you unzipped the AWS icons.
Select the icon you want to insert and click "Insert".
Adjust the Inserted Icons:

Once the icon is inserted into your slide, you can resize, rotate, and move it as needed.
If you’re using SVG icons, you can also change their color directly in PowerPoint.
Save Your Presentation:

After you have finished adding and arranging your AWS icons, save your PowerPoint presentation.

Remember that AWS regularly updates its icon set to reflect new services and changes in existing services, so it's a good idea to check for the latest icon set periodically.